# flatten a list of int array

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I have a list of int arrays in Java 7.
At the end,I need to flatten out the entire list into a single concatenated int array.

```
List<int[]> list=new ArrayList<int[]>();
list.add(new int[]{0,1});
list.add(new int[]{2,3});
System.out.println(list.flatten());

Output expected - 
int[]{0,1,2,3}
```

What would be the most elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use streams:

removed - Java 7 was sneaked in later!

I don't think you can make it any more elegant than:

```
int newlen = 0;
for( int[] a: list ){
    newlen += a.length;
}
int[] out = new int[newlen];
int pos = 0;
for( int[] a: list ){
    System.arraycopy( a, 0, out, pos, a.length );
    pos += a.length;
}
```

Comment: This would not be an option in java 7